# How to use plugins in Action Files Vue JS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

We are using https://github.com/mazipan/vue2-simplert-plugin

In our Main.js

```
import Simplert from 'vue2-simplert-plugin'
Vue.use(Simplert)
```

In the xxx.vue file, we can call

```
var infoMessageBox= {
  message: "",
  type: 'info',
  onClose: this.onClose
};
this.$Simplert.open(infoMessageBox);
```

This can work normally.

Now the tricky part comes. We will call dispatch (Action file) a method. Below code is example:

```
var requestMessage = {
  customerId: "",
  accessToken: "",
  store: this.$store,
  redirect: true,
  insideThis: this,
  network: "",
  alertbox: this.$Simplert,
};
this.$store.dispatch('checkIfCustomerExists', requestMessage);
```

Here is the action file

```
import Vue from "vue";

export const checkIfCustomerExists = (context, request) => {
  var infoMessageBox= {
    message: "",
    type: 'info',
    onClose: this.onClose
  };
  request.alertBox.open(infoMessageBox)
};
```

Above code will work and show the alert. This will work because I passed the this.$Simplert as parameter.

But I dont want to pass everytime to the parameter. I want to access it somehow inside this action file. I need to do some import or something like that?? How can I use this Simplert without sending it as parameter.

**Update 1: Suggestion is to use bus event.**
I created a file            event-bus.js

```
  import Vue from 'vue';
  export const EventBus = new Vue();
```

In the Vue file I do emit:

```
  import { EventBus } from '../../../../store/event-bus.js';


EventBus.$emit('i-got-clicked',this.$Simplert);

var requestMessage = {
  customerId: "",
  accessToken: "",
  store: this.$store,
  redirect: true,
  insideThis: this,
  network: "",
  alertbox: this.$Simplert,
};
this.$store.dispatch('checkIfCustomerExists', requestMessage);
```

However in the action file.

```
  import { EventBus } from '../../../../store/event-bus.js';

  EventBus.$on('i-got-clicked', Simplert => {
    console.log("adsasda");
    Simplert.open(infoMessageBox);
});
```

console is not printing. So I suppose this is not active.

Comment: Have you considered using an event bus? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication

Comment: @Phil no I did not. Someone else also suggested that. But isnt there a simple way like import or something ?

Comment: Not sure. Doesn't look like Simplert has a _global_ access mode, especially considering it needs a `<simplert>` element in your template somewhere. Perhaps you could put in a feature request. It might be available but is just not documented

Comment: Yes actually I did that in App.vue  
  <simplert></simplert>

Comment: But with bus it is possible ?

Comment: Can't see why not. You emit an event to the bus in your store and listen for the event in your main Vue app. Reading the doco for the simplert plugin, it seems it also uses an event bus so maybe you could tap in to that somehow. Sorry for the ambiguity but their doco is kinda hard to read

Comment: Found it, it's called [SimplertEventBus](https://github.com/mazipan/vue2-simplert-plugin/blob/master/src/simplert-event-bus.js)

Comment: I am not pro in this bus related topic. I put screenshot this didnt generate anything but the errors dissappeared.

Comment: I'd raise a feature request asking for the `SimplertEventBus` to be exposed via export so it can be used globally.

Comment: @Phil I did this event bus in my code. But this on part is not working. Any idea why ? I updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the plugin already uses an event bus for triggering the open / close events so you should be able to tap in to that via the plugin instance registered into `Vue`

In your store, try

```
import Vue from 'vue'

// snip

export const checkIfCustomerExists = (context, request) => {
  // snip
  Vue.prototype.$Simplert.open(infoMessageBox)
}
```

---

Note, this seems pretty hacky to me. I'd advise you to raise a feature request with the maintainers to expose the `SimplertEventBus` so it can be used globally.

Comment: Yes that worked. But for any other type of similar stuff is there a practical way? Like not all import related stuff have this bus I  guess. I maybe then put in the bus emit then try to get with on?

Comment: That totally depends on how things have been implemented in the 3rd party add-ons.